# Inverse function of $f(x) = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt[3]{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

> Let $f: [0, 2] \to [0, \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{2}]$ and $f(x) = 
> \sqrt{x} + \sqrt[3]{x}$.
>
> Show that $f$ has a continuous and monotonically increasing inverse function $g: [0, \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{2}] \to [0, 2]$ that's differentiable on $(0, \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{2})$.

My approach was to first determine if $f$ is injective and then if it's surjective, but differentiating $f$ results in $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{3x^\frac{2}{3}}$ from which i cannot deduce that $f$ would be monotonically increasing since $f'(0)$ is undefined. What's the alternative approach here?

Comment: By the mean value theorem, for any $x>0$, there exists $c\in(0,x)$ such that $f(x)-f(0)=xf'(c)>0$. Then $f'(x)>0$. Therefore, $f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: You can avoid having to use derivatives altogether doing an argument like this: $g:t\mapsto t^6$ is increasing and $f(g(t))=t^3+t^2$, which you can see easier that is increasing by the arithmetic properties of $>$. In fact, if $0\leq s<t$, then $s^3<t^3$ and also $s^2<t^2$. Therefore, $f(g(s))=s^3+s^2<t^3+t^2=f(g(t))$. Now, $g^{-1}:t\mapsto t^{1/6}$ is also increasing. Therefore, $f(t)=f(g(g^{-1}(t)))$ is a composition of the two increasing functions $f(g(t))$ and $g^{-1}(t)$.

Comment: Well, for the proof that the inverse is differentiable you do need to compute derivatives.

Comment: Daniel. $x^{1/2}, x^{1/3}$ are strictly increasing, so is their sum. Surjective : Image $f([0,2])=[0,2^1/2+2^{1/3}]$, and since $f$ is continuos, $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(x)>0$ for $x \in (0,2)$, then $f$ is strictly increasing, so it is at least injective. Since $f(2) = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{2}$, which is the upper bound of the codomain, then $f$ is surjective as well.